# Jquery+условие.

Tags: jquery

Нужно написать условие:
Если все элементы на странице с классом .test равны test, то.
Делаю так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!$(".test").html == "test"){
console.log('good');
}
});
```

На странице расположено несколько <p class="test">

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testPassed = true;
    $(".test").each(function(key, val) {
        if ($(val).html() != "test") {
            return testPassed = false;
        }
    });
    if (testPassed) {
        // тест прошел успешно, выполняемый необходимый код
        console.log('test has been successfully passed');
    }
});
```